# In R-tree, can I use x,y coordinate as the search key?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, geolocation

In an R-tree, if the leaf nodes are rectangles, what is used for a key to the search of rectangles?

For example, suppose we are given any random x,y-coordinate `(a, b)` that lies **inside** rectangle `X`. Of course `(a, b)` is not stored in the data structure.

If I call `search()` with `(a, b)` as arguments, will it return `X`?

Or do the arguments have to be something else about `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set things up in a straightforward manner, then yes, it will return `X` and all other rectangles containing `(a, b)`.

Setting things up in a straightforward manner means that each internal node will wrap its children as tightly as possible. In theory, you could also set things up differently; it depends on the question you want to answer. For example, if you want to know "what rectangles are within 2 units of distance of `(a, b)`?", then you could make each interior node pretend that each leaf is two units larger than it actually is (in all directions). Then the same search query would return a set of rectangles that contains all rectangles within two units of distance, and potentially a few that are further away, which you could filter out.

If you'll want to answer such other questions, you'll generally need to know this before building the tree.